# Saving profile picture of users in php

Tags: php, database, base64, profile, pic

I have created a app in php. How i can save the profile pictures of the users? Will that be a good idea to save them in db using base64 encode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692060/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-users-images-using-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 2):

upload them on the server and save the path on the database

Answer (score 1):

Store images in your server and store the path to images in the database. This will reduce extra overload on database server.